# I want to route to 2 different CELERY_BROKER_URL

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I want to use 2 different CELERY_BROKER_URL for 2 different IP's and specific task should go in the another URL (ex - redis://127.0.0.2:6379).

**environment file**

```
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED=True
CELERY_BROKER_URL="redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
```

**celery.py**

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'engine.settings')

app = Celery('engine')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Enable sending the "task-sent" notification.
app.conf.task_send_sent_event=True

app.conf.database_engine_options = {'echo': True}

# load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Comment: Nothing stops you from writing the code that sends tasks to workers that use different brokers. Your producer code can instantiate two (or more) Celery objects, both with different brokers, and use `send_task()` to send tasks to run on the right set of workers.

Comment: Hii.. thank you for your response. But what I wanted to do is create a single celery object with multiple broker URLs and route each task to separate brokers. I have two tasks which I want to send to two different queues.

Comment: I believe that is not possible. You need to make two Celery instances with different broker settings.

Comment: What if I make 2 different queue in the same broker URL and give routes to different task? FYI - I'm using redis

Comment: It may work, but I have never experimented with that so i can't give you any advice. Why don't you try by youself?